# Saving model on each change, except the first initial fetch

Tags: backbone.js

I'm sure it's a very common and basic Backbone question, but I couldn't find the answer

I would like to save a model after each change, *except* the initial fetch from the server.

For example:

```
  MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "myModelUrl",
    initialize: function () {
      this.on("change", this.save, this);
    }
  });
```

When fetching it, since it has some data, I get a change event, and then save is triggered again

```
 var myModel = new MyModel({id:"123"}); 
 myModel.fetch();
```

Is there a way to avoid the first save on the first fetch? (e.g. if the model was just fetched, don't save)

Could it be that the only way is to [bootsrtap the models](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap)?

e.g. based on the documentation, is this really the only way to do it?

> Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped in to place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for interfaces that are not needed immediately: for example, documents with collections of notes that may be toggled open and closed.

**Edit:**

One issue I see with bootstrapping is this - it seems I have to fetch my entire collection on page load, I can't fetch only small parts of it. Why? because if my routes use a hash tag, on page refresh, the server side won't know which route I'm in (hash part is not sent to the server). e.g. only if I use pushState: true I can get to be able to bootsrap the right model / collection on page refresh, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sync` is the event that is fired when a model is fetched. Listen to the `sync` even only once. Later to that listen to `change` event on the model.

```
var self;     
this.listenToOnce(model,'sync', function(){
   self.listenTo(model,'change',self.changeHandler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that's what I was looking for. p.s. I think that for `listenTo` and `listenToOnce`, Backbone passes the context object on the method call (it uses on and once), e.g. I think `this` is being set to the view, e.g. no need to save the `self` reference. let me verify though. In any case thanks, great solution!

Comment: Yep, no need for `var self` Backbone does the magic here for you. But your solution of course works, and I think is simply great, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand your requirements. But if you just want to avoid the first save, you could manually set an attribute

```
isFirstSave = true
```

and make your binding methods like this

```
onModelChange: =>
  if @isFirstSave
    @isFirstSave = false
  else
    @save()
```

Ugly but works..